# C# preserve escape sequence when reading JSON content using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, regex

C# preserve escape sequence when reading JSON content using Json.NET

Given the following json text content:

```
{ "Pattern": "[0-9]*\t[a-z]+" }
```

Which is reflected in a simple class:

```
public class Rule
{
    public string Pattern { get; set; }

    public bool Test(string text)
    {
        return new Regex(Pattern).IsMatch(text);
    }    
}
```

And it's deserialised like this:

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.json");
var rule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rule>(text);
```

The value of `Pattern` is supposed to be a regex pattern. The problem is that, once the content is read, the "`\t`" escape sequence is immediately applied as a escape character which is a tab, resulting in the string value: `[0-9]*    [a-z]+`.

What I understand is that the content is somewhat malformed, because it *should* look like this: `[0-9]*\\t[a-z]+` to be valid within the Json content, escaping the backslash so it could be preserved and result into the actual pattern `[0-9]*\t[a-z]+`. But the file is user edited and I would just like to be able to loosely interpret the content, assuming that backslashes should be preserved (and escape sequences would not be transformed).

I tried to implement a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iwu3n9) but when looking up the token, the value is already resolved.

[FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iwu3n9)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but aren't those patterns equivalent? `\t` or a tab should give the same result with regex, no?

Comment: `user edited`. Can't you just assume that if a user is able to edit a `JSON` file he knows that backslashes needs to be escaped?

Comment: @Rob that's maybe true, yes, in the case of `\t` but with the complexity of Regex, the changes are getting low

Comment: @MichaelMairegger yes I could, but I know how the users work, they use a tool like **regexhero.net** and copy the regex pattern around, change it, copy again.... A complex pattern can have multiple occurances. It would be great if they could just also paste it into our config file, the chances are high to make a mistake when the value is pasted. [* the only exception is to not include " which would break the string but we don't want that within a regex]

Comment: I believe the problem is somewhere else: in a file, `\t` is a literal ``\`` with a literal `t` and should be read in as `"\\t"` C string.

Comment: For what its worth, changing to a string literal fixes it.
`var text = @"{ ""Pattern"": ""[0-9]*\\t[a-z]+"" }";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the below code and it works...maybe i don't understand what is the problem or you can provide a sample that doesn't work with this:

```
StreamReader s= new StreamReader(@"test.txt");
string json = s.ReadToEnd();
json=json.Replace("\\","\\\\");
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
string pattern = obj["Pattern"].ToString();
bool test = Regex.IsMatch("1    a", pattern);
```

test.txt contains just this:

```
{ "Pattern": "[0-9]*\t[a-z]+" }
```

**Edit**
As [Thomasjaworsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265165/thomasjaworski-com) remarks, instead of `json=json.Replace("\\","\\\\");` is better to use `Regex.Replace(json, @"(?<!\\)[\\](?!\\)", @"\\")`
, it will do the same replace, but only if not already escaped. Two backspaces in row are untouched.

Comment: OK, so I didn't choose a good example. `\t` is actually working just like the tab, you're right. But the `Parse` command will fail if you for example write replace `\t` with `\.` to match a period e.g. `1.a`. Also, if you for example, would want to Log the pattern somewhere (e.g. to the console) `Console.WriteLine(pattern)` it will render to tab.

Comment: O.k. i see. Wouldn't it work in my example if after `string json = s.ReadToEnd();` you add this line: `json=json.Replace("\\","\\\\");`? This way `Console.WriteLine(pattern)` will also work

Comment: Thanks Pikoh that works! With the downside that it's applied to the whole content, I can't really isolate this to the regex patterns only.

Comment: Yes...you have to do it before parsing it,but i don't thing it's a big problem, because it just replaces the '\' with '\\', doesn't affect anything else. Glad it works for you! :)

Comment: I'm not doing `Replace("\\","\\\\")` but instead `Regex.Replace(json, @"(?<!\\)[\\](?!\\)", @"\\")`, it will do the same replace, but only if not already escaped. Two backspaces in row are untouched.

Comment: Even better. I've edit the answer so others can see it